# Ruby on rails - Showing featured posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a blog application with Ruby on Rails and would like to show 30 'featured' articles on the home page.

I have considered using a boolean attribute 'featured' on the articles table, however I have some issues with this;

1. If I have 4000 articles, I have to search through all of them just to find the 30 that are featured.
2. 3970 articles will have an empty column.

I'm wondering if there is a better way - such as creating another DB table that stores just the ID's of the featured articles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site aimed at providing answers to specific technical questions. Your question is a request for architectural direction which depends on opinion and will attract excess debate. Please review the SO [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for information on how to ask good questions that receive good questions. To illustrate the point, consider using a persistent structure in memory that holds your short list of featured article IDs, which would be much faster than anything relying on the DB. Now onsider the many ways to implement just this one approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case the best decision would be to use model scope for featured articles.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  scope :featured, -> { where(featured: true) }
end
```

and use this scope from your rails view

```
<% @articles.featured.each do |article| %>
  <p><%= link_to article.subject, article_path(article) %></p>
<% end>
```

[Link to scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) from Ruby on Rails Guide